# Delphi error: missing '@VarFromLStr' under iOS Simulator

Tags: delphi

I have this error `[DCC Fatal Error] UnitUtf8.pas(52): E2158 System.Variants unit out of date or corrupted: missing '@VarFromLStr'` on compiling simple test

```
var
  S_ENG_UP: string = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
  S_ENG_LO: string = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';
  ...
const
  NullValue = 'NullValue';


implementation

{$R *.fmx}

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  i, j: integer;
  s: string;
  TestData: Variant;
begin
  TestData := VarArrayOf([
      VarArrayOf([NullValue, UTF8Encode(S_ENG_UP), UTF8Encode(S_ENG_UP), S_ENG_UP, S_ENG_UP]),
      VarArrayOf([NullValue, UTF8Encode(S_ENG_LO), UTF8Encode(S_ENG_LO), S_ENG_LO, S_ENG_LO]),
      VarArrayOf([NullValue, UTF8Encode(S_RUS_UP), UTF8Encode(S_RUS_UP), S_RUS_UP, S_RUS_UP]),
      VarArrayOf([NullValue, UTF8Encode(S_RUS_LO), UTF8Encode(S_RUS_LO), S_RUS_LO, S_RUS_LO])
    ]);
  for i := VarArrayLowBound(TestData, 1) to VarArrayHighBound(TestData, 1) do
    for j := VarArrayLowBound(TestData[i], 1) to VarArrayHighBound(TestData[i], 1) do begin
      s := VarToStr(TestData[i][j]);
      Memo1.Lines.Add(s);
    end;
end;
```

under both XE6 and XE7 for iOS Simulator platform. But everything fine under Win32/64. Was unable to find solution and it seems everything "As intended" since I have it under both XE6/7. Should I recompile System.Variants (how?) or there is some workarounds? Second attempt to build gives me `[DCC Fatal Error] UnitUtf8.pas(52): F2084 Internal Error: AV08603536-R00000004-0`. I need to test exactly as array of Variant since I should check why another custom (probably copy of some older UTF8Encode made for compatibility since Delphi 5) gives me different results for national codepage under Windows and iOS Simulator (yes, it is garbage after UTF8Encode, but it is different garbage).

Comment: Why use variants on iOS? Surely TValue is the right choice.

Comment: That's up to Delphi 5 compatible DAC component and I have no big choice what to use. And why not use Variant? Is this `VarFromLStr` from Windows dlls?

Comment: How do you get the Delphi 5 dac component to run on iOS? Why are you still using ANSI? Resisting progress will make your life hard.

Comment: It's TDS implementation (Sql Server direct). ANSI because, well, Sql Server have half types as ANSI, also ANSI used in connection and UDP resolving. We can't avoid using ANSI (for MacOS and iOS reimplemented). And it is not only for iOS.

Comment: I very much doubt that using ANSI is a good idea. You'll just be making life hard for yourself.

Comment: If field data received in packet as ANSI, should be sent as ANSI, why not store such type inside as ANSI - is there better ideas how to avoid using ANSI while people keep using ANSI fields in tables? We can't forbid Microsoft using ANSI. There is no choice. I can understand progress and stuff, but there is real tasks to do.

Comment: Use the native type internally. Convert to other encodings, if needed, at interop boundaries.

Comment: So `VarFromLStr` removed by Embarcadero from compiled unit for iOS because it's ANSI operation? And UTF8Encode returns ANSI (RawByteString it seems) result, that why I have this error? Variant here should have varString VType inside (AnsiString), right? Just to understand what exactly happens.

Comment: There is no AnsiString on mobile platforms. I trust you already know that.

Comment: Are you compiling a custom Variants unit?

Comment: No. If code above causes Variant to act as AnsiString (disabled/removed in Variants.pas for iOS) then you can post it as answer and I'll mark it as answer.

Comment: I'm not sure that I can write a good answer.  I think it would be better for you to write the answer. Thanks,